# SQL - Selecting All Except

Tags: sql

I have a table of NBA player stats of all NBA players from January 1 to January 7. The data in the table is set up exactly like it is here: http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=1&year=2014

I'm trying to run a query to return the stats for when a list of players from different teams do not play due to injury. When a player does not play, he is not listed in the player column for that date. Right now I have a query that returns the stats for when players DO play:

```
select
    t2.player,
    count(t2.player) as Game_Count,
    t2.tm,
    round(avg(t2.minutes), 2) as Min
from
    nba.player_stats t1
        inner join
    nba.player_stats t2 ON t1.date = t2.date and t1.tm = t2.tm
where
    t1.player = 'Courtney Lee'
        or t1.player = 'Ryan Anderson'
group by player;
```

This returns [image]

There are three listed teams here because Courtney Lee was traded from BOS to MEM between the 1-01-14 and 1-07-14.

I'm trying to return all data except for the selected. This includes all other teams (ATL, BRK, etc.) I was thinking just saying "player<>" instead of "player=" and using distinct would work, but doing that produces some results that don't make sense to me (game count should be no more than 5):
[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Your query seems to be doing more than you are describing... Is this supposed to get all players from team of Courtneylee/ryananderson that didn't play?  Where is a list of all players?

Comment: The attempted query here is trying to get all data of games where Courtney Lee and Ryan Anderson did not play. This includes a) all players on other teams they are not a part of and b) all players on their teams on only games where they did not play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand the question - you're looking for all player stats for those teams in which the selected players did NOT play in that year?

I'm going to suggest using NOT IN and a nested query here. This is a bit simpler.  In addition, use the IN statement to list the players instead of multiple conditions.

```
select
    t.player,
    count(t.player) as Game_Count,
    t.tm,
    round(avg(t.minutes), 2) as Min
from
    nba.player_stats t
where
    t.tm not in (
                 select tm from nba.player_stats p
                 where  p.player in ('Courtney Lee','Ryan Anderson')
                        and p.date = t.date)
group by player;
```

Comment: Yes exactly. This did it, thank you so much, I appreciate it. This has been giving me a headache for the past week.